# Make Check Box Mandatory field in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react js . I want to make sure the user has to select atleast 1 checkbox using reactjs.
The checkbox values i have taken is dynamic which is zone_name.
Below is the code:

```
    addCheckbox() {
    const { zones_to_render_to_render } = this.state,
        label = this.refs.label.value;

    zones_to_render_to_render.push({
        checked: true,
        label
    });

    this.setState({
        zones_to_render_to_render: zones_to_render_to_render.zone_name
    });
}

toggleCheckbox(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { zones_to_render_to_render } = this.state;

    zones_to_render_to_render.checked = !zones_to_render_to_render.checked;

    this.setState({
        zones_to_render_to_render
    });
}
renderCheckboxes() {
    const { zones_to_render_to_render, filter } = this.state;
    console.log(zones_to_render_to_render, filter)
    return zones_to_render_to_render
        .filter(checkbox =>
            filter === 'ALL' ||
            filter === 'CHECKED' && checkbox.checked ||
            filter === 'UNCHECKED' && !checkbox.checked
        )
        .map((checkbox, index) =>
            // console.log(checkbox, index)
            <div key={index}>
                <label>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        checked={checkbox.checked}
                        onChange={this.toggleCheckbox.bind(index)}
                    />
                    {checkbox.zone_name}
                </label>
            </div>
        );
}
```

Without Selecting atleast 1 checkbox should not allow .